# I need to validate if first character of a string is a letter and next characters are either letters or numbers or special characters _,-,. and space

Tags: c#, regex

Please note:All characters are in English only.

I tried 
`Regex.IsMatch(item, @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$")` 
but doesn't work expectedly

Comment: It looks fine but it requires at least two chars. Try `Regex.IsMatch(item, @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$")`

Comment: "Does not work" is **never** a proper problem-description. Please add what results you get and what you expected instead. This includes some sample data, of course.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me so far, can you please elaborate what "doesn't work expectedly" exactly means? With sample data?

Comment: Could you provide *some tests*? E.g. are `A` (one letter only), `Щ` (one *Russian* letter), `a...`, `a-2.56-`, `Щ2` valid ones?

Comment: The proper answer also depends on what you mean with letter. If a letter is just A-Z and you are fine with ignoring German (e.g. äöü), French (e.g. áâàç), Skandinavian (e.g. å), Cyrillic, Chinese, etc. letters then `A-Z` is correct. If you want to match any kind of letter then you should use `\p{L}` which matches the Unicode category Letter.

Comment: The last dash in the pattern is the issue.  Since a dash indicates a range like a-z you cannot use the dash as a single character.  So try \-

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the expression provided by you doesn't allow spaces in the middle of name

Comment: letter means a-z and A-Z

Comment: @jdweng: Dash at first or last position in a character class doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Just add space in the second character class

Comment: @RenéVogt try this Regex.IsMatch("hjkk hjk", @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$") <-This doesn't take space in the middle of names

Comment: @Vikash Kumar: so you want *several* (one more) names separated by *(white-)spaces* where each name must start from *letter* and can contain *letters*, *digits* or special symbols(`_`, `.`, `-`)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko no,just the first letter of the complete string

Comment: What "name"? Your question is not about *names*. If it is, it is too broad - you cannot match any arbitrary *names* with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex.IsMatch(item, @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_. -]*$")

There is a space between '.' and '-'

Thanks all for your suggestions.
My sample inputs are:
Vikash,Vikash kumar,Vikash. kumar,Vikash9_. kumar <-these should be supported

and

9Vikash,Vikash*hj,Vikash&9,%ghj <-these shouldn't be supported

Comment: Should `"a    -    _ -  "` be matched?